# Creating a view on two tables and the view should not allow any DML operations

Tags: oracle

one of the questions I have to do from school asks me to do the following:

"Create a view called TITLE_UNAVAIL to show the movie titles and media_id of
the media not returned yet. The view should not allow any DML operations. "

This is my script:

```
CREATE VIEW TITLE_UNAVAIL7
FROM RENTAL_HISTORY7
SELECT title, media_id
WHERE return_date = null
```

and I get the error saying:

> "ORA-00905: missing ketword"

Can someone advise on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It's amazing what you can find in [the documentation!](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_8004.htm#i2105040)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you should read the documentation: [CREATE VIEW](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_8004.htm#SQLRF01504)

```
CREATE VIEW TITLE_UNAVAIL7 AS
SELECT title, media_id
FROM RENTAL_HISTORY7
WHERE return_date IS null;
```

This will be the standard answer (as you see form other people). In order to prevent any DML on this view, add `WITH READ ONLY`, i.e.

```
CREATE VIEW TITLE_UNAVAIL7 AS
SELECT title, media_id
FROM RENTAL_HISTORY7
WHERE return_date IS null
WITH READ ONLY;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the right [syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_8004.htm#SQLRF01504); also, you can not check a column for `null` values with `= null`, but you need `is null`

```
CREATE VIEW TITLE_UNAVAIL7 AS
SELECT title, media_id
FROM RENTAL_HISTORY7
WHERE return_date is null
```